# Why is the getSystemService(string) method just a stub in the Activity class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-service

I'm just learning Android so I was poking around a bit and learning some new keyboard shortcuts in Android Studio. I did a quick definition lookup on the `getSystemService(string)` method and it pulled this up:

[image]

Is the source for this method hidden somehow? It can't really just throw a `RuntimeException`, right....?

Comment: Do you have the Sources downloaded in the SDK Manager?

Comment: I have the SDK for API level 23 and 24 downloaded. Is that why it isn't showing me the true source? Because it's looking for API 21?

Comment: You might have the SDK, but that doesn't include sources and documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a stub but the source is hidden, a proof for this can be seen when you actually invoke this method and it works desirably.

Moreover you would find many such methods in various classes which are a part of `Android Framework`, they do not expose actual logic that deals with framework.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Is there any reason they hide the source here when you could just find it online?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to really see what `getSystemService` does, look at the android source code on [Github](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base).

This is the inheritance tree.

[Activity](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java) -> [ContextThemeWrapper](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.java) -> [Context](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/Context.java)

Inside `Context.java` you can find what it actually does.

```
/**
 * Return the handle to a system-level service by class.
 * <p>
 * Currently available classes are:
 * {@link android.view.WindowManager}, {@link android.view.LayoutInflater},
 * {@link android.app.ActivityManager}, {@link android.os.PowerManager},
 * {@link android.app.AlarmManager}, {@link android.app.NotificationManager},
 * {@link android.app.KeyguardManager}, {@link android.location.LocationManager},
 * {@link android.app.SearchManager}, {@link android.os.Vibrator},
 * {@link android.net.ConnectivityManager},
 * {@link android.net.wifi.WifiManager},
 * {@link android.media.AudioManager}, {@link android.media.MediaRouter},
 * {@link android.telephony.TelephonyManager}, {@link android.telephony.SubscriptionManager},
 * {@link android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager},
 * {@link android.app.UiModeManager}, {@link android.app.DownloadManager},
 * {@link android.os.BatteryManager}, {@link android.app.job.JobScheduler},
 * {@link android.app.usage.NetworkStatsManager}.
 * </p><p>
 * Note: System services obtained via this API may be closely associated with
 * the Context in which they are obtained from.  In general, do not share the
 * service objects between various different contexts (Activities, Applications,
 * Services, Providers, etc.)
 * </p>
 *
 * @param serviceClass The class of the desired service.
 * @return The service or null if the class is not a supported system service.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public final <T> T getSystemService(Class<T> serviceClass) {
    // Because subclasses may override getSystemService(String) we cannot
    // perform a lookup by class alone.  We must first map the class to its
    // service name then invoke the string-based method.
    String serviceName = getSystemServiceName(serviceClass);
    return serviceName != null ? (T)getSystemService(serviceName) : null;
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. I was actually just looking at the Activity class source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-2.3.5_r1/core/java/android/app/Activity.java) and it looks like Activity's implementation is different than Context's (I realize Activity inherits from Context).